# Redirect remotely through controller action without reloading window

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried this!

```
def create
  @event = Event.new(params[:event])
  if @event.save
    render js: %(window.location.pathname='#{new_meal_path(@event)}')
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

and this

```
def create
  @event = Event.new(params[:event])
  if @event.save
    redirect_to new_meal_path(@event), format: 'js'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

The first instance reloads and redirects the window to the requested path while the second instance tries to redirect remotely but doesnt call the responding js file.Could someone please try help me try and redirect to requested action without reloading the window.

Comment: It seems like what you want is to render the new action and replace the inner content of your page, right?

Comment: yes. that's what I actually need

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible. The browser cannot be redirected without reloading the window.